# int input with a string and a variable

Tags: python, input

I'm somewhat new to python and am working on an assignment with a friend for school.
We wanted to ask for a swimmer's name, followed by asking what time they managed to achieve. 
We wanted the program to work like this:

```
Name = input('Input swimmers name: ')
Time = int(input('What time did',Name,'achieve? ')
```

However it isn't working. What could we use here that will allow us to ask the swimmer's time by using the swimmer's name in the question?

Comment: `'foo' + Name + 'bar'`

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass a single string to `input`, you can do it by first concatenating your 3 strings:

```
Time = int(input('What time did' + Name + 'achieve? ')
```

BTW: "achieve" with an "e" ;-)

Comment: You could also use: 
`Time = int(input('What time did {} acheive? '.format(Name))`.
I also wouldn't use `int()` there, in case someone inputs 0:56.15 or something.

Comment: Thanks for that man, Im super surprised at how fast this was answered.

Comment: @Andrew this is actually slower: see my comment in other answer.

Comment: @JulienBernu Interesting. I find the `format` syntax more readable, but good to know that the alternative is faster if I ever have to optimise.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use %s for concatenation

```
Time = int(input('What time did %s achive? ' % Name ))
```

Comment: If you want your answer to be better you can back up your "is faster than +" with some source :)

Comment: Especially when it is wrong... `%timeit 'What time did %s achive? ' % "toto"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 99 ns per loop` but `%timeit 'What time did ' + 'toto' + ' achive?'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 38.8 ns per loop` (Note that I'm not the downvoter ;-) and for completeness: `%timeit 'What time did {} acheive? '.format('toto') 1000000 loops, best of 3: 204 ns per loop`

Comment: Thanks @grael, Julien for this. Have corrected. learnt something.